# Operating on multiple specific folders at once with cp and rm commands

Tags: bash, cp, rm

I'm new to linux (using bash) and I wanted to ask about something that I do often while I work, I'll give two examples.

1. Deleting multiple specific folders inside a certain directory.
2. Copying multiple specific folders into a ceratin directory.

I succesfully done this with **files**, using find with some regex and then using -exec and -delete. But for folders I found it more problematic, because I had problem pipelining the list of folders I got to the cp/rm command succescfully, each time getting the "No such file or directory error".

Looking online I found the following command (in my case for copying all folders starting with a Z):

`cp -r $(ls -A | grep "Z*") destination`

But when I execute it it says nothing and the prompt won't show up again until I hit Ctrl+C and nothing is copied.

How can I achieve what I'm looking for? For both `cp` and `rm`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Looks quite a complex discussion in there. Are you implying I should use for ; do ; done for this? (iterating over them?)

Comment: @Argento, yes use a loop or `find`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are trying to grep "Z*" but it means you are looking for Z, ZZ, ZZZZ, ZZZZZ ?
also try to execute ls -A - you will get multiple columns. I think need at least ls -1A to print result one per line.
So for your command try something like:

```
cp -r $(ls -1A|grep "^p") destination
```

or

```
cp -r $(ls -1A|grep "^p") -t destination
```

But all the above is just to correct syntax of your example.
It is much better to use **find**. Just in case try to put target directory in quotas like:

```
find <PATH_FROM> -type d -exec cp -r \"{}\" -t target \;
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Would you mind explaining the elemnts `\"{}\"` and `\;` ?

Comment: {} in find command means current item from list
\"\" - escaped quotas, so just in case if target item will contain spaces, etc - each each item will be put in quotas
\; means end of command in -exec option

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!